# Dealing with Byte Order Mark (BOM) in R

Tags: r, data.table, byte-order-mark, read.csv, readr

Sometimes a Byte Order Mark (BOM) is present at the beginning of a .CSV file. The symbol is not visible when you open the file using Notepad or Excel, however, When you read the file in R using various methods, you will different symbols in the name of first column. here is an example

A sample csv file with BOM in the beginning.

```
ID,title,clean_title,clean_title_id
1,0 - 0,,0
2,"""0 - 1,000,000""",,0
27448,"20yr. rope walker
igger",Rope Walker Igger,1832700817
```

Reading through `read.csv` in base R package

```
(x1 = read.csv("file1.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#   ï..ID                raw_title        semi_clean semi_clean_id
# 1     1                    0 - 0                               0
# 2     2          "0 - 1,000,000"                               0
# 3 27448 20yr. rope walker\nigger Rope Walker Igger    1832700817
```

Reading through `fread` in data.table package

```
(x2 = data.table::fread("file1.csv"))
#    ï»¿ID                raw_title        semi_clean semi_clean_id
# 1:     1                    0 - 0                               0
# 2:     2        ""0 - 1,000,000""                               0
# 3: 27448 20yr. rope walker\rigger Rope Walker Igger    1832700817
```

Reading through `read_csv` in readr package

```
(x3 = readr::read_csv("file1.csv"))
#   <U+FEFF>ID                raw_title        semi_clean semi_clean_id
# 1          1                    0 - 0              <NA>             0
# 2          2          "0 - 1,000,000"              <NA>             0
# 3      27448 20yr. rope walker\rigger Rope Walker Igger    1832700817
```

You can notice different characters in front of variable name ID.

Here are the results when you run names on all of these

```
names(x1)
# [1] "ï..ID"         "raw_title"     "semi_clean"    "semi_clean_id"
names(x2)
# [1] "ï»¿ID"         "raw_title"     "semi_clean"    "semi_clean_id"
names(x3)
# [1] "ID"             "raw_title"     "semi_clean"    "semi_clean_id"
```

In `x3`, there is nothing 'visible' in front of `ID`, but when  you check

```
names(x3)[[1]]=="ID"
# [1] FALSE
```

How to get rid of these unwanted character in each case.
PS: Please add more methods to read csv files, the problem faced and the solutions.

Comment: Uh you need to check your spellings of rigger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For read.csv in base R use:

```
x1 = read.csv("file1.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
```

For fread, use:

```
x2 = fread("file1.csv")
setnames(x2, "ï»¿ID", "ID")
```

For read_csv, use:

```
x3 = readr::read_csv("file1.csv")
setDT(X3) #convert into data tables, so that setnames can be used
setnames(x3, "\uFEFFID", "ID")
```

One non-R based solution is open the file in Notepad++, save the file after change encoding to "Encoding in UTF-8 without BOM"

Comment: For folks coming here looking for authoritative info on BOMs & R after being frustrated with the inanity of Windows data files, you should also hit this —https://github.com/ropenscilabs/gtfsr/issues/19#issuecomment-247766324 — this — https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/be3bf6e2b7e8b06648fd — this — https://github.com/hadley/readr/issues/263 — and this — https://github.com/hadley/readr/issues/500.

Comment: Post-hoc approaches are to be avoided, I'd say. Better to attack the problem at its source. Also, don't use `as.data.table` in most cases. Use `setDT`, since it doesn't create a copy.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico, I have modified the answer. However I am not skilled enough to even understand how to attack the problem at source.

Comment: No worries! That's not necessarily on you. I would report the issue for `readr`; in fact, there is already a well-upvoted issue on [`readr`'s GH page](https://github.com/hadley/readr/issues/500)